# Missing space after \addfontfeature

Tags: fontspec

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

My text\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+onum} and more words.

\end{document}
```

Compiling it (both with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX), there is no space in the output between "text" and "and". Given that `\addfontfeature` has an argument in braces, I wouldn't expect such a behavior. Once one knows of it, avoiding the problem is trivial... But I wonder about the reason of it.

Comment: It is by design and documented: "\fontspec and \addfontfeatures ignore trailing spaces ..."

Comment: @UlrikeFisher Thanks!